# In wpf how can i reference MainWindowViewModel from other ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am developing a wpf/xaml app for windows.  I want to use the material design framework and i have loosely based my app on the code from the example application here: http://materialdesigninxaml.net/ My C#/xaml knowledge is ok, but very rusty.

In this implementation there is a MainWindow.xaml view linked to a MainWindowViewModel, where the MainWindowViewModel is handling the data conversion from the model and the presentation logic.

My question is about the best design philosophy to use for the 'pages' that are viewed in the MainWindow.xaml - i have an app working where i can navigate through 'pages'. So the main window has a store of potential pages in a `ObservableCollection` and shows navigation buttons. Clicking on the buttons goes to the next page in the `ObservableCollection`.
My question is about how the pageViewModel can interact with the MainWindowViewModel.  For example a user might click a button on a pageView to cause a command that moves to another page - to do this using this framework requires an ICommand to be actioned on the  MainWindowViewModel.

What i have done so far is have the MainWindowViewModel create the other pageViewModels.  On instantiation the pageViewModels save a reference to the MainWindowViewModel that can code on MainWindowViewModel can executed when needed.  This seems to work but also i can't help thinking there would be a more optimal solution.

I have been doing some looking at similar questions on SO - do I need to look into `IEventAggregator`?

Comment: Passing a main view model reference to a child view model is a legit approach. Are you just asking for opinions? IMO the navigation buttons should simply not be on the pages, but instead somewhere in the main view.

Comment: you may also use some event bus implementation [fx. i'm using Catel MVVM framework so I'm using IMessageMediator](https://docs.catelproject.com/5.12/catel-core/messaging/message-mediator)

Comment: @celemens thanks - just wanting some experience - i was looking at some tutorials on the PRISM libraries and they seem to simplify commands and messaging between ViewModels.  i like the idea of messaging instead of inheriting references because it decouples things. for the buttons example i was thinking of a login page -after you log in you need to navigate somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use an UI Framework like [caliburn micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/). This framework will connect a View automatically with the corresponding ViewModel. There is also a so called [conductor](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition). The conductor allows to use multiple pages with it´s own View and ViewModels in a main page. It also provides activation and deactivation behaviour and many more. May it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> What i have done so far is have the MainWindowViewModel create the other pageViewModels. On instantiation the pageViewModels save a reference to the MainWindowViewModel that can code on MainWindowViewModel can executed when needed.

This is one approach. The problem with it is that it creates a tight coupling between the view model classes.

A better and common approach is to use an event aggregator or a messenger to communicate between the view models. This removes the tight coupling as a subscriber of an "event" or "message" only observes the event aggregator instead of the publisher and the publisher knows only about the event aggregator and not about the subscribers.

Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) blog post for more information about the concept.